# PIC18F45K80 QT1481 with software EUART and SPI

Tags: c, pic, spi

So I've successfully managed to send `0x0F` to sensor and receiving a response `0xF0`. Now, what I would like to do is see on the software EUART that I have sent `0x0F` to the sensor and receive a message back when `0xF0` has been received from the sensor.

This is code that I and my friend developed but cannot get our head around. I also attach screenshots of what I see.[image]
 [image]

So the main code I experimenting with:

```
while(1){
    char temp;
     __delay_us(100); // required previous to check DRDY (pag 26)
    while (PORTDbits.RD5 == 0) ; // wait until DRDY high
    QTA_SS_LAT_LOW ; // Put SS low
    __delay_us(10); // required if you are QT was in sleep mode (pag 22)
    WriteSPI(0x0F); // Send a byte - Transmit data
    __delay_us(2); // Wait for the byte to be shifted out
    QTA_SS_LAT_HIGH ; // Put SS high
    out_str("Sent 0x0F ",10,LSB);

    // Now transfer null command for getting the response
    __delay_us(100); // required previous to check DRDY (pag 26)
    while (PORTDbits.RD5 == 0) ; // wait until DRDY high
    QTA_SS_LAT_LOW ; // Put SS low
    __delay_us(10); // required if you are QT was in sleep mode
    temp = ReadSPI(); // Read a byte from the
    QTA_SS_LAT_HIGH ; // Stop transmitting data
    out_str("Received 0xF0 ",14,LSB);
}
```

And the `out_str();` function:

```
void out_str(char * string, uint8_t len, char bit_order){
  uint8_t i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i< len; i++){
    out_char(string[i], bit_order);
  }
}
```

Software EUART should be outputing in pin RB5 and the SPI from dedicated pins for MOSI, MISO, DRDY and SS

SPI works fire without software EUART.[image]

For software euart I using docklight.

Comment: You can user uart sniffer to monitor what is being send and received trough the bus.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ksL6-d5Qui-_skyJnAaNlaWvD07GvwR6/view?usp=sharing

The schematic above implies the connection is half-duplex. If full duplex it is possible to get garbage data